# Back button when using the same activity for different views

Tags: android, listview

I have a `Listview` that I am populating with data from sqlite database and I am using the same activity to load different data in it, when a row of the `Listview` is clicked it displays information in another `Activity`, so my question is how to handle the back button so it takes to the appropriate list.

1st button clicked :

```
Intent i=new Intent(Hotel.class.this,Activity_hotel);
 i.putExtra("btn",1);
 startActivity(i);
```

2nd button clicked :

```
Intent i=new Intent(Hotel.class.this,Activity_hotel.class);
i.putExtra("btn",2);
startActivity(i);
```

for back button :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent home_intent = new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),Hotel.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(home_intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

edited :

in the MainActivity

```
      case 2:
         Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hotel.class);
        String lien="hotel";
        intent3.putExtra("choix",lien);
         startActivity(intent3);
       break;
        case 3:
             Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hotel.class);
             lien="restaurant";
            intent4.putExtra("choix",lien);
               startActivity(intent4);
          break;
```

Hotel.class :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel);



    mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
        mDbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mDbHelper.openDataBase();


     Intent i = getIntent();

     String choix = i.getStringExtra("choix");

    c = mDbHelper.fetchAllservices(choix); //récupération des données 


    startManagingCursor(c);

  String[] fromColumns = {DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME};  //from
  int[] toViews = {R.id.name}; // to


     // définition des éléments de la liste
     dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rows_services, c, fromColumns, toViews, 0);




     list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);  //afficher la liste


  list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
             int position, long id) {


               nom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name); // nom c'est memID_tv 

               String nom_val = nom.getText().toString();  // nom_val c'est memberID_val 

               Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ExtendList.class);  // ExtendList c'est Modify_member

               modify_intent.putExtra("thename", nom_val); // thename c'est memberID
            startActivity(modify_intent);
         }
          });
```

Details activity (ExtendList.class )

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_daughter);
     dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

     try {
            dbHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
     } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     dbHelper.openDataBase();


     name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
     adresse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adresse);
     numtel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tel);
     email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
     website = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.website);
     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);


     Intent i = getIntent();

     String thename = i.getStringExtra("thename");  // thename c'est membername ( memberID )




     services = new Service();
     services = dbHelper.Get_ServicesNAME(thename);

     path = services.image;

     Resources res = getResources();
     int resId = res.getIdentifier(path, "drawable", "com.example.guide_oran");
     img.setImageResource(resId);

     name.setText( services.name);
     adresse.setText(services.adresse);
     numtel.setText(services.numtel);
     email.setText(services.email);
     website.setText(services.website);

}













public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Hotel.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


                    home_intent.putExtra("choix",choix); // THE SOLUTION I WAS SEARCHING FOR 

        startActivity(home_intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

hope i've provided all details.
thanks ( PROBLEM SOLVED, i've added the solution to the post )

Comment: I got question, are you using onListItemClick??

Comment: So you want that if the user navigates from activity A to B and then presses back, the activity A should display the same data set it displayed before?

Comment: Activity stack is managed by framework, so you don't need to put implementation for going back to the calling activity.

Comment: Use finish() instead of creating a new activity

Comment: @DushyantPatel i am using OnItemClickListener.

Comment: @Cata yes that's exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @choco ok then why should you override the back method.. the system will take care of that for you.. could you tell us in what activity lifecycle method do you set the adapter data set for the list? a full code of your activity's onCreate or onResume would help better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be this following snippnet:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            Hotel.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(home_intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Actually, (**even with your edited solution**) this is your new `Intent` which causes the problem to return to the previous list. When you return to `Hotel.class`, you reinitialize this activity. Then, your ListView is removed and reuploaded.

To avoid this, why don't you can just call `finish()` method to destroy your actual activity and return to `Hotel` activity? That being said, **you will not recreate the activity and use resources again to repopulate your list**.

I think, you should use another method to handle the back state as follows:

```
// Use this method to handle the back button pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();  
     // then, just finish ExtendList.class
     this.finish();
}
```

Then `ExtendList` activity is destroyed whereas `Hotel` activity, which was still behind, comes up and displays your previous list, without doing anything more.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Really glad to help. With this, at least, you will not recreate your activity again and again. Sometimes, you have to trust in android OS ;)) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This code will be look like this :

```
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("btn").equals("1"))
                {
                    // go to appropraite activity
                }
                else if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("btn").equals("2"))
                {
                    // go to appropraite activity
                }
            }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: but i'm using just one activity with different data.. and data are not saved so when i return it force close

Comment: Update question with logcat